# How to make transparent element while dragging in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have a card element that can be dragged from one column to another column. This works, except the card has a transparent dropzone element inside it that becomes opaque on Chrome browsers when dragging. This problem is not the case on Firefox or Safari.

You can see the code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Ustad/3dn6sqpm/14/).
How can I fix this problem on Chrome browsers?
I tried by playing with opacity and rgb() in css, but with no success. See the code below.

```css
#board {
    display: flex;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 800px;
}

#board * {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.board__column {
    flex: 1;
    background: #fcb51d;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.board__column:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.board__column-title {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    user-select: none;
}

.board__item-card {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
  background: white;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

.board__item-input {
    background: white;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.board__dropzone {
    height: 10px;
    transition: background 0.15s, height 0.15s;
}

.board__dropzone--active {
    height: 20px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.board__add-item {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="board">
            <!-- Todo's tasks -->
            <div class="board__column">
              <div class="board__column-title">Todo</div>
              <div class="board__column-items">
          <div class="board__card" draggable="true">
            <div class="board__item-card">
              My first todo task 
            </div>
             <div class="board__dropzone"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="board__card" draggable="true">
            <div class="board__item-card">
              My second todo task...
            </div>
            <div class="board__dropzone"></div>
          </div>
              </div>
              <button class="board__add-item" type="button">+ Add card</button>
            </div>
            
            <!-- In progress tasks -->
            <div class="board__column">
              <div class="board__column-title">In Progress</div>
              <div class="board__column-items">
          <div class="board__card" draggable="true">
            <div class="board__item-card">
              I'm working on the task 
            </div>
            <div class="board__dropzone"></div>
          </div>
              </div>
              <button class="board__add-item" type="button">+ Add card</button>
            </div>
            
            <!-- Done tasks -->
            <div class="board__column">
              <div class="board__column-title">Done</div>
              <div class="board__column-items">
          <div class="board__item-card"  draggable="true">
            <div class="board__item-card">
                  I finished the task 
                </div>
                <div class="board__dropzone"></div>
          </div>
              </div>
              <button class="board__add-item" type="button">+ Add card</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Believe it is not the dropzone div element that is turning opaque, I believe that the `board__card` element being draggable forces it somehow to inherit the color of its parent, please check the following link:

[Why HTML draggable element drags with parent background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61812276/why-html-draggable-element-drags-with-parent-background)

Comment: I haven't tested yet but the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61812377/1012775 might do the trick. I'm not sure if that's a good practice way, but if it works I'll use it.